# multiplying part of dataframe based on time condition with specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to multiply values within a specified time with a value

Tried the following which works when I do it once, however I think I cannot reassign multiple times. Only 1 line works, but more than one gives NaN. How to circumvent this while still applying the multiplications to the specific time ranges?

```
onpeak_increase  = 1.2
offpeak_decrease = 0.8
df2 = df2.between_time('07:00:00', '11:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=False) * onpeak_increase
df2 = df2.between_time('16:00:00', '20:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=False) * onpeak_increase
df2 = df2.between_time('20:00:00', '07:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=True) * offpeak_decrease
df2 = df2.between_time('11:00:00', '16:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=False) * offpeak_decrease
```

Comment: please create an example (5 rows should be enough) and a expected output

Comment: It's not really something to try, i would like someone to point me in the right direction how to do multiplications on different ranges of time in one dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `df.between_time` extract the corresponding rows, so you are setting your dataframe to those rows at each step.
So if i understand well what you want,i will do something like that :

```
idx = df2.between_time('07:00:00', '11:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=False).index
df2.loc[idx] = df2.loc[idx].values * onpeak_increase

idx = df2.between_time('16:00:00', '20:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=False).index
df2.loc[idx] = df2.loc[idx].values * onpeak_increase

idx = df2.between_time('20:00:00', '07:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=True).index
df2.loc[idx] = df2.loc[idx].values * offpeak_decrease

idx = df2.between_time('11:00:00', '16:00:00', include_start=True, include_end=False).index
df2.loc[idx] = df2.loc[idx].values * offpeak_decrease
```

I take as supposition that you want to multiply the values of the row corresponding to that range

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i needed. Very grateful. Thanks for you fast solution!

Comment: Glad to have helped you !